# Retrieve values from NSDictionary with same keys

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"image1.jpg" forKey:@"USA"];
[dict setObject:@"image2.jpg" forKey:@"USA"];
[dict setObject:@"image3.jpg" forKey:@"USA"];
[dict setObject:@"image1.jpg" forKey:@"Brazil"];
[dict setObject:@"image2.jpg" forKey:@"Brazil"];
```

If I use:

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
```

Fine, I got a {USA, Brazil} Array.

All I want is a code that I get all objects for USA. If I use:

```
NSArray *objectsforKey = [dict objectForKey:@"USA"];
```

I will get an array with only one item: **image1.jpg**
Same issue for valueforKey.
I need all values for that key. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure you know how a dictionary works. Setting a new value for a given key will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: You really need to store images in array, inside the dictionary with the unique country keys.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to know logic behind this. If you want to do this because you are getting multiple values for a key. Then you can set these value in an array after that add that array in your NSDictionary. As I know this will work for you.

Comment: You should add `[dict setObject:@[@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg"] forKey:@"USA"];`

Comment: You only inserted two elements above.  That's why you can only retrieve two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not possible. NSDictionary only stores one object per key. In your code you are replacing the previous object, when calling `setObject:forKey:`.

The solution is to store arrays inside the dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *USAImages = [NSMutableArray array];
[USAImages addObject:@"image1.jpg"];
[USAImages addObject:@"image2.jpg"];
[USAImages addObject:@"image3.jpg"];
dict[@"USA"] = USAImages;

NSMutableArray *BrazilImages = [NSMutableArray array];
[BrazilImages addObject:@"image1.jpg"];
[BrazilImages addObject:@"image2.jpg"];
dict[@"Brazil"] = BrazilImages;
```

Now you can get your filenames like this:

```
NSArray *USA = dict[@"USA"]; // @[@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg",@"image3.jpg"]
NSArray *Brazil = dict[@"Brazil"]; // @[@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg"]
```

Comment: Thanks Florion for your answer. I thought about doing that but tha data will be retrieved by a API, and it will be needed a lot of nsarrays, so I need to do it programatically.

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn't be a problem. Just create the arrays dynamically at runtime and add them to the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible.
You should add an array-

```
 [dict setObject:@[@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg"] forKey:@"USA"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually key should be unique. If you will set like this key "USA" will have value last value as "image3.jpg" and key "Brazil" will override "image1.jpg" with "image2.jpg".